# Unique solution for AX=b

Tags: linear-algebra

Give one condition on A such that AX=b will have a unique solution for all $b\in \mathbb{R}^2$ where $A:\mathbb{R}^3\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

I believe the answer should be: A is invertible that is the function A($L_A$) is one-one and onto so that b has a unique pre-image.

Am I correct in saying that?

Comment: $A$ isn't square, so it can't be invertible.

Comment: You’re right that $b$ would be unique if $A$ were *square* and invertible, but you can’t invert a rectangular matrix. What are some conditions that are equivalent to invertibility for square matrices that could be seen in rectangular matrices?

Comment: Think about the rank

Comment: No doubt you meant $b\in\mathbb R^2$, since $AX$ is a vector, not a scalar.

Comment: This is something of a trick question, I think. Given the dimensions of the domain and codomain, can there _ever_ be a unique solution?

Answer (score 1):

In general, given a matrix $A$ of type $(m,n)$, if the system $Ax=b\;$ is compatible, the (affine) space $S$ of its solutions has dimension

$$ \dim(S)=n-\text{rank}(A).$$

In the case considered we have

$$ \dim(S)=3-\text{rank}(A) \geq 1 $$

because $\text{rank}(A)\leq 2$. Therefore the given system can never have a unique solution.

It is obvious that the conclusion immediately generalizes to the case $m<n$.